# NPM --save dúvida

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

Qual diferença na hora de instalar um módulo via NPM, utilizar o --save?

Ao usar npm install nomedomodulo, ele instala igual e gravar os modulos na pasta do projeto.

Não entendi então quando usar npm install nomedomodulo --save

Alguem pra me ajudar?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

O `--save` salva o pacote no arquivo `package.json`, que serve de referência para o seu projeto. Logo quando você utiliza o comando `npm install` todos os módulos que foram instalado com o `--save` serão instalados sem a necessidade de defini-los um a um.

Referenciando a [documentação do npm install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install):

> **-S**, **--save**: Pacote irá aparecer nas dependências.

Comment: O que seria  defini-los um a um?

Comment: ter que dar `npm install fs`, `npm install bower` um a um em todas as máquinas em que o projeto for baixado. Após você fazer a primeira instalação, se você precisar instalar no servidor por exemplo você só dá um `npm install` puramente

Comment: No momento não estou utilizando o package.json, o que pode acontecer de ruim com isso?

Comment: Se não me falha a memória só não irá gravar no arquivo, então seria a msm coisa que um `npm install xxx` normal

Comment: Acabei de testar, é isso msm que acontece

Comment: Só completando, digamos que você quer mandar esse projeto para mim, seria inviável me mandar a pasta node_modules, pra isso, existe o package.json. Você me manda apenas o package.json e os arquivos que você programou e eu uso um npm install na minha máquina, esse npm install vai ler o package.json e instalar as dependências.

Comment: Então nesse package.json fica registrado todos os módulos que instalei? inclusive a versão deles?

Comment: Exatamente. Serve justamente pra vc garantir que terá as mesmas dependências em tds os lugares, entre outras utilidades

Comment: Bacana. Quando eu salvo meu projeto no git, os  modules não vao junto então? Apenas meu projeto?

Comment: Sim, essa é a idéia, você pode dar um `ignore` na pasta `node_modules`

Comment: entendi. Pra fechar, na hora que eu clono o projeto do git, não precisa dar um npm install NOMEDOMODULO? Ele pega automaticamente do do package.json? Ou tenho algum npm update sei la....

Comment: tem que dar um comando só: `npm install`

Comment: Ao digitar npm install ele procura todas dependências do package e instala os módulos?

Comment: Exatamente. Você troca por apenas 1 comando evitando erros